# Current Release of Salesforce ,what is SU13

Tags: community, developer, dev401

What is meant by SU13,Today I have registered for Salesforce.com Certified Force.com Developer (SU13) -dev401 certification. The current release as per salesforce release document is Winter 14, So do I get Examination questions depending on Summer 13 or Winter 14.Please help me to get sort out this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the current upcoming release may be winter 14, certification exames lag behind a bit. It usually takes a few weeks till after the release before you can take the new certification exam or the release exames.

Comment: hi ,Thankyou for a quick reply..Suppose i have a question in the certification exam which have different answer with respect to Summer'13 and Winter'14 ,then which answer should i opt to take as answer.And also im using an org for practice purpose which is showing the summer'13 logo,so would the help and training page would be specific to latest version or the version to which my org belongs.Please help me

Comment: Most questions and answers won't be much version specific, but if there are area's of difference, answer with what is applicable to summer 13.

Answer (score 2):

If the examination states SU13 implies you will not get questions related to winter 14 .The latest features launched in winter 14 you need not go through from examination perspective as these wont come .SU13 means summer 13 so you will need to get familiar up to features available in the platform till Summer 13 release .(Including summer 13)

Comment: hi Mohith,Thankyou for a quick reply..Suppose i have a question in the certification exam which have different answer with respect to Summer'13 and Winter'14 ,then which answer should i opt to take as answer.And also im using an org for practice purpose which is showing the summer'13 logo,so would the help and training page would be specific to latest version or the version to which my org belongs.Please help me